# macOS - Java 17 installed with asdf: No such file or directory when checking java version

Tags: java, macos, adoptopenjdk, asdf-vm

I installed Java 17 version with [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com) and it works without any problems in a Java project:

```
➜  ~ asdf list java
  adoptopenjdk-17.0.0+35
```

But when checking the java version with `java -version` in the terminal, it displays the following errors:

```
~ java -version
/Users/xxx/.asdf/shims/java: line 3: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asdf/0.8.1_1/libexec/bin/asdf: No such file or directory
/Users/xxx/.asdf/shims/java: line 3: exec: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/asdf/0.8.1_1/libexec/bin/asdf: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Oh My Zsh terminal and the following line:

```
. /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
```

added after installation o `asdf` is the last one in the `.zshrc` file.

What's wrong with that? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This solved the issue for me:

1. rename the `~/.asdf/shims` directory
2. run `asdf reshim`

[More details](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/1147#issuecomment-1006067709).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can use
rm -rf ~/.asdf/shims

Comment: Thank you ! `asdf reshim` was enough for me.

Comment: zsh: permission denied: /Users/xxx/.asdf/shims when doing first step

Answer (score 2):

Try

```sh
asdf global java adoptopenjdk-17.0.0+35

asdf reshim
```

It sets `adoptopenjdk-17.0.0+35` as default for the user and then asdf will update the shims.